# Custom WinForm ListBox with user-input content

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a need to provide as options multiple objects from a particular data set, and populate a list so that an end-user can select, none,some, all, or all + possibly missing data fields (user-input).

I originally planned to extend a System.Windows.Forms.ListView to include a whitespace item that contained a checkmark, then specially handle the case where a user had clicked this blank line item.

I would like the ability to remove these user-input line items if possible.  I do not have to use a System.Windows.Forms.ListView, but its design seems to best-fit this particular use.

Is there a control with this functionality already , or an attribute of the System.Windows.Forms.ListView I have missed that may handle these situtations?

---*Update*---

> ```
> ListBox is changed to System.Windows.Forms.ListView
> ```

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid sounds like it would be a good fit; otherwise I'd suggest looking at 3rd party controls.